# Drupal 8 ignores block display settings for the default content block, if it is configured to be hidden on a node page

Tags: 8, nodes, blocks

can someone help me understanding this scenario (D8): My content type - let's call it basic page - has two fields; title and body. I have a node (id = 33) with path /url. On the block layout page I have disabled both 'page title' and 'page content' blocks for path = /url, and instead I have created my own block (using a view) that displays the title and body together. This block is set to be SHOWN for path = /url.

Now when I navigate /url, I expect to see the title and body. Instead I see the title, body and again the title and body. Inspecting the markup reveals that the default content block is not hidden (as it should be, according to the block layout page).

I have seen this behaviour now on a couple of projects, I get the same issue if I use node/33 or if I set this node as the home page and use front. It seems Drupal 8 ignores the block display settings for the default content block if you set it as invisible on a node page.

Why is this happening?

Comment: While speaking with @seanr on the Drupal slack channel, I came up with the following: By removing fields on the Admin -> Structure -> Content Types -> [your type] -> Manage Display page, force the default content block to be empty. While this fixed my issue, the fact that the block is displayed at all (when it is set to be hidden, as per normal Drupal instructions) feels weird.

Comment: I think the "default content block" is not processed like a block. It's built in an earlier phase for a start.